# Left Join using apache beam and Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have two  BigQuery tables and I want to perform Left join. If right table is smaller then its working fin; but when right table size is equal to left table, then it's taking too much of processing power. Both tables contains around 7 million records.

Kindly suggest me approach to do that.

Comment: *you could have it trigger a query that just does all this from within bigquery, and pass the result to dataflow.

Comment: Its part of a big project so I can't do it manually or some seperate  Query

Comment: what I mean is that you can use a big query query as the source/input for your dataflow pipeline.  In general, that approach scales much further than dataflow reading in entirety of tables on its own.